# How to fix topology seams

Tags: modeling

I am trying to model a part of an airplane. I have a problem with some slight distortions in the mesh. How can I fix this so that it  looks like a smooth continuous surface.

[image]

What it should look like:

[image]

[**blend file**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27716)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a method that works to some extent, it is not perfect but I think it is the best that can be done with the topology.

1. Duplicate the mesh

   - we will use this to create a seamless version
2. Delete the faces where the cutout for the seat is

   - this is the geometry that is causing the problem

   [image]
3. Select the edges at the ends of the hole and use the *Grid Fill* tool, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

   - The grid fille we fill the hole with some nice polygons, these will not look distorted

   [image]
4. Add a subdivision surface modifier to the mesh

   [image]
5. Select the mesh with the topology for the hole
6. In edit mode select the faces at the hole and a few faces and around it as well

   [image]
7. Add the faces to a vertex group.

   [image]
8. Add a shrink wrap modifier to the mesh with the hole

   - Select as the *Target* the mesh without the hole
   - Select as the *Vertex Group* the vertex group we created in step 8

   [image]

### **Final Result**

[image]